# rPython can't find Pandas

Tags: python, r, pandas, shiny, rpython

I seem to be having trouble with running a python app on my shiny server with rPython.

I set my python sys path,

```
Sys.setenv(PATH = paste("/Users/timmcwilliams/anaconda2/bin/", Sys.getenv("PATH"),sep=":"))
```

Then I checked if it worked with,

```
  system("python --version")

Python 2.7.14 :: Anaconda, Inc.
```

Finally, I also check my PATH,

```
 Sys.getenv("PATH")
[1] "/Users/timmcwilliams/anaconda2/bin/:/Users/timmcwilliams/anaconda2/bin/:/Users/timmcwilliams/anaconda2/bin/:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin"
```

So, I figured it worked correctly. But it seems to not have worked.

```
runApp('app')

Listening on http://127.0.0.1:4062
Warning: Error in python.exec: No module named pandas
Stack trace (innermost first):
    39: python.exec
    38: python.load
    37: server [/Users/timmcwilliams/Code/Scripts/search-microwave/app/server.R#10]
     1: runApp
Error in python.exec(code, get.exception) : No module named pandas
```

But I have pandas installed. I am really not sure why this is happening. Both python versions are the same `2.7.14` and I am positive I have Pandas installed because I use it on daily.

Comment: I had a similar problem using `reticulate`. What worked for me was to run the `import` statements in `R` outside of the python document: `sapply(c("import mysql.connector", "import re"), py_run_string)` before `source_python("app.py")`

Comment: @divibisan Using `reticulate` I was able to get rid of the Pandas error. Now it is throwing a different one. `Error in python.exec(code, get.exception) : 
  Missing required dependencies ['numpy']`. I went and followed the same methods to get Pandas to work, but I think this is different. Maybe I need to upgrade `rPython` or something